# No connection to MariaDB

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I want to connect to my database and transfer the data, I got from the DHT22. But it won't execute
cur.execute(..).
As you can see I put an print("h") in there, which never gets printed, it only prints the Test.
Would really appreciate your help guys.

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_dht
import mariadb
import sys
from datetime import datetime

dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D17)


conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="root",
    password="password",
    host="localhost",
    database="messstation")
cur = conn.cursor()
x = 0


while x < 5:
    x = x+1
    time.sleep(2.0)
    try:
        # Print the values to the serial port
        temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
        humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
        print('Temp', temperature_c)
        print('Humidty:', humidity)
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        try: 
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO messstation (uhrzeit,luftfeuchtigkeit, raumtemperatur) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (dt_string, temperature_c, humidity)) 
            print("h")
            conn.commit()
        except: 
            print("Test")
    except:
        print("Not working")
        pass
conn.close()
```

Comment: checklist: 1. is the database existing? 2. is it accessible from where you are trying to access it? verify it with `select user, host from mysql.user;` you should see "root, localhost"
3. are the tables where you are trying to insert data existing? If not, create them

Comment: Try printing the Exception message to see what is causing it
`except Exception as ex:    print(ex)`

Comment: Yes I added all of this, here are the screenshots.
[link](https://prnt.sc/1v5qrmd)
[link](https://prnt.sc/1v5qmtb)
[link](https://prnt.sc/1v5qlv8)
@SaverioGuzzo

Comment: It tells me Table messstation.messstation doesn't exist @ujjaldey

Comment: The message is quite clear. Verify that you have the table `messstation` in db `messstation`

Answer (score 0):

I had to put in INSERT INTO root. After that it worked fine.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).